# How can I get a number from a specific pattern in a string?

Tags: php, regex

The string is:

```
I really love apples. gallery="67,65,60,49,45" Bananas are cool too.
```

And I only want the 67 (the first integer in the sequence, regardless what it is). I can't seem to match it. My regex isn't so good, and I've tried googling but I haven't been able to put the right characters together.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `explode` and `array_shift`

Comment: Why not just split on the comma delimiter and then grab the first item in the array

Comment: Sorry, I simplified too much and made the solution different that it should be. The string is more like how I just edited it to. The gallery="..." can take place anywhere in a paragraph, which is why I was having a problem

Comment: Giving a new sample string really doesn't help as we still don't know how that string may be different from instance to instance. Try and describe the format of the string and what may and what may not change. Also, add your solution that didn't pan out. With those things done, the question may get reopened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like this:

```
^\d+
```

The `^` is an anchor that matches the beginning of the string. That way, you will match "a number of any length that is at the beginning of the string".

**EDIT:**

For your new requirement, use

```
(?<=gallery=")\d+
```

That will match the number you want.

Comment: Sorry, I simplified too much and made the solution different that it should be. The string is more like how I just edited it to. The gallery="..." can take place anywhere in a paragraph, which is why I was having a problem

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regex for this. You can  use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) to split the string with the delimiter comma and then simply print it.

```
$gallery="67,65,60,49,45";
$var = explode(',', $gallery);
echo $var[0]; //outputs 67
```

**Demo: http://codepad.org/aCWySInp**

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, I simplified too much and made the solution different that it should be. The string is more like how I just edited it to. The gallery="..." can take place anywhere in a paragraph, which is why I was having a problem

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Does that mean your issue is resolved?

Comment: No, I meant that misrepresented it. I'm not trying to get the first number of "67,65,60,49,45". I've edited the example in my question to make it a little more clear of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
$gallery = "67,65,60,49,45"; 
echo explode(',', $gallery)[0]; // will echo '67'
```

Comment: Sorry, I simplified too much and made the solution different that it should be. The string is more like how I just edited it to. The gallery="..." can take place anywhere in a paragraph, which is why I was having a problem